# angular9 ngfor removing object from array shows undefined error

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have an array of items which are objects.
The items are called from a service and shown when I go on the cart page.

When I click the remove button I run `delete this.cart.items[i];`.
this.cart is my service, and removes the item from the object. It successfully does this on the page too but I then get a blank element and errors in console saying `Cannot read property 'qty' of undefined`.
I assumed the ngfor will auto update the the DOM and remove the element as that object no longer exists.
Would I also have to remove the element from the DOM manually?

from the array below, I wanted to remove the first item completely but still show the second.

```
[
  {
    "desc": "Description",
    "item": "item 1",
    "id": "1",
    "portion": "small",
    "price": "4.25",
    "qty": 3
  },
  {
    "desc": "Description",
    "item": "item 2",
    "id": "2",
    "portion": "large",
    "price": "4",
    "qty": 1
  }
]


<div class="cart-item" *ngFor="let item of items" (click)='ontap(item);'>
    {{ x.item }}
</div>
```

this is where I display it, but it still shows the elemnt with no data.
Thanks

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: have you try to remove an item like this `this.cart.items.splice(i,1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this `delete this.cart.items[i]` is not  the correct way to remove an element from an array the delete statement remove the item but still the length of the array is the same

```js
this.cart.items.splice(i,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ngFor` with index to get the index on your button click:

```html
<div class="cart-item" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" (click)='onRemove(i);'>
    {{ x.item }}
</div>
```

Then use that index to remove from array and reassign the resulting array to itself:

```
onRemove(index: number) {
   this.items = [...this.items.splice(index, 1)]
}
```

**NOTE:** The spread operator is used to trigger the change detection on Angular.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using onPush strategy with your `dumb` component then the value in DOM will not update.

You have to write it like this e.g:

```
let itemsWithoutRemoved = this.cart.items.splice(i, 1);

this.cart = {
...this.cart,
items: itemsWithoutRemoved 
}
```

Then your view will update as the Input has changed.

Also, removing an item from array is done via `splice` method.